# How should I approach generating recommendations for fish stock management?

Tags: machine-learning, python, statistics, simulation

I've been asked to "Model and study the size and age composition of fish populations as dynamical systems for a given area and generate recommendations for seasonal fish stock management based on model output analysis."

The data I have available are taken from fishing reports and for each fishing trip I have the **species** of fish caught, the **weight** of fish caught, the **time**, the **location**, the **time spent fishing** and the **fishing gear** type used. Therefore, I understand that I may not be able to study the *age composition* of the stock, without the appropriate data.

The model and analysis shall include ocean temperatures, currents, salinity, meteorological and other available relevant and available data such as euphotic depth and dissolved oxygen concentrations.

How would you recommend I approach this project? Any advice on appropriate models to use will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to ask is always, "*why* are we doing this?" Is it for sustainable fishing? Maximize the amount of fish caught? The purpose of the project leads to very different approach.

Second thing to ask is, "*what* are some possible recommendations, and what constraints are there?" It is a waste of time to recommend something at the end of project which is not executable.

The principle is NOT mess with all the data/models/buzzwords first, but set out to **understand the problem and background**. Have you discussed with the stakeholders (e.g. professor, business owner) about the project scope? What do you know about fishing population? Have you done your literature review on what have been done by others? What approach they took and what conclusion was drawn?

Garbage in, garbage out. Don't randomly dump some data in some model and pray - it just gives you garbage back. Not how data science works.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've included those questions for requirement refinement next week. I have started a literature review, although a lot of the papers include methods about the age-structure of a population. I just need recommendations for alternative methods to fuel my literature review.